# Como não afetar o <body> com uma função JS e pegar o valor somente da class requerida?

Tags: javascript, jquery, aplicação-web

#### index.html

```
<body class="teste">
<h1 id="teste-zica">teste</h1>
<h2>teste2</h2>
<h3>teste3</h3>
```

#### js.js

```
addEventListener("mouseover", paradaDeSucesso);
function paradaDeSucesso(event) {
    $(event.target).addClass("intro");
    this.addEventListener("click", function(){
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("intro")[0].textContent;
        $(event.target).removeClass("intro");
    });
}
```

O problema é o seguinte: toda vez o meu `hover` ta pegando o `body`, e assim quando clico ele pega o valor todo, não era pra acontecer isso, há um meio de travar o `addClass` para a tag `body`?

PS: O que eu quero fazer é o deixar o local que o mouse está com a tag e assim que ele for clicado pegar o conteúdo daquela Class, "intro" no caso, para usar em outra função para traduzir para libras o conteúdo que foi clicado.

Comment: Não estou a ver em que caso será útil usar um evento tão abrangente, mas testa `event.stopPropagation();` para evitar que o evento volte ao `body`, mas sem explicares melhor o que queres fazer é dificil ajudar.

Comment: @Sergio estou desenvolvendo uma API de tradução de pt-br pra libras, ao meu ver tenho que ter uma class/id para identificar o conteúdo a ser pêgo pelo sistema para fazer a tradução.

Comment: Ok, nesse caso é melhor juntares esse `addEventListener` a cada elemento. Podes dar um exemplo do HTML?

Comment: Eu confesso que não entendi bem o queres fazer.. pode criar um exemplo de código para ficar mais claro? Pode ser aqui ou no https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @RicardoPontual https://jsfiddle.net/tkssyvme/ aqui está, desculpe pela demora, no caso a classe está indo pro body e também html, gostaria de não passar porque caso o usuário clique irá pegar todo o texto da página.

Comment: @Sergio https://jsfiddle.net/tkssyvme/ aqui está o exemplo, quando o cursor do mouse fica em algum lugar que não sobre as divs e etc ele acaba ficando em cima do body e assim pega adiciona a classe "giulia" nele, caso clicado pega todo o texto, gostaria de evitar isso. Agradeço desde já a ajuda!

Comment: @MatheusAzevedo a ver se percebo: quando o mouse passa por cima de um elemento (qualquer que seja) ele adiciona a classe. Depois queres tirar a classe ao clicar no elemento e também ler o seu conteúdo é isso? e pode ser um elemento qualquer ou queres limitar só a alguns?

Comment: @Sergio no clique ele irá pegar o texto que ele clicou, só irá remover a classe quando o usuário tirar o mouse de cima, o problema é que quando ele posiciona no em cima do body, o mesmo fica com a classe e isso não deve ocorrer.

Comment: @MatheusAzevedo então só queres evitar que o `body` receba a classe é isso? de resto pode dar/tirar classe e clicar em todos os elementos?

Comment: @Sergio exatamente!

Comment: @sergio há como fazer?